# JSoup not sees table on web page

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, html-parser, javaparser

I want to get a table from a web page:

```html
<table class="coupon-row-item coupone-labels">...</table>
```

I use

```java
Element market = page.select("table[class=coupon-row-item coupone-labels").first();
```

And get

> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Did not find balanced marker at 'class=coupon-row-item coupone-labels'

Full function

```java
protected void getMainMarked(ArrayList<String> arrLinks) throws IOException {
    Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(arrLinks.get(0)), 5000);
    Element market = page.select("table[class=coupon-row-item coupone-labels").first();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose to try following selector syntax (as described in [Jsoup documentation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)):

```
Element el = doc.select("table.coupon-row-item.coupone-labels").first();
```